# Doubt about lemma for polynomial equivalence

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, quadratic-forms, isomorphism-testing

Multivariate polynomials $f,g$ are equivalent if there exists
invertible linear transformation $A$ such that $f(X)=g(A\cdot X)$

From [paper p.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Poly20Equiv.pdf):

> Lemma 1.1. (Structure of quadratic polynomials). Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic
> different from 2.
> For any homogeneous quadratic polynomial $f(X) \in F[X]$
> there exists an invertible linear
> transformation $A \in F^{n \times n}$ and a natural number $1 \le r \le n$ such that
> $f (A \cdot X) = x_1^2 + x_2^2 + . . . + x_r^2$
> Moreover, the linear transformation $A$ involved in this equivalence can be computed efficiently.
> Furthermore, two
> quadratic forms are equivalent if and only if they have the same number r of variables in the above canonical
> representation.

Let $F$ be the algebraic closure of the rationals.

Basically there are more than $n$ non-equivalent $f_i$
and only $n$ possible choices for $r$.

Fix $n$ and take $n+1$ non-equivalent $f_i$.
By the pigeonhole principle there are at least two $r_i=r_j$,
contradicting non equivalence of $f_i$.

> Q1 What is wrong with this argument against the lemma?

> Q2 Is homogeneous quadratic polynomial equivalence
> or isomorphism polynomial in $n$?

Comment: You assumption that "Basically there are infinitely many non-equivalent $f$" is false. Try writing out the proof for 2 variables and you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @JoeSilverman Thanks. I edited with "there are more than n non-equivalent f_i", is this true? I will accept as an answer correctness of the lemma.

Comment: why do you say that there are more than $n$ non-equivalent homogeneous quadratic polynomials in $n$ variables when the lemma asserts there are exactly $n$?

Answer (score 3):

The lemma is correct, and there are indeed no more than $n$ non-equivalent $f_{i}$. Here is a sketch of a proof:
We can do a transformation such that the coefficient of (without loss of generality) $a_{1}^2$ is non zero, and by scaling, 1. Now by replacing $a_1$ with $a_1 - c_2 \cdot a_2 - \dotsb - c_n \cdot a_n$, where the coefficients $c_i$ are chosen appropriately, we can ensure that $a_{1}^2$ is the only place where $a_1$ appears, and now we can induct on the statement with $n-1$ variables.

Comment: Many thanks Random.

Comment: Is this related to efficient quadratic polynomial isomorphism: $f(X)=g(\pi(X))$ for permutation $\pi$?

Comment: TeX note:  literal `...` (as $a_1 - c_2\cdot a_2 - ... - c_n\cdot a_n$) doesn't behave well in TeX; prefer (between binary operators) `\dotsb` (as $a_1 - c_2\cdot a_2 - \dotsb - c_n\cdot a_n$).  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @joro I'm not sure I understand exactly what you meanby related, but a permutation is an example of polynomial equivalence.

Comment: @Lspice I see, thank you.

Comment: I mean: given quadratic $f(X)$ and $f(\pi(X))$ can you recognize it is isomorphism, not just equivalence?